# Does celery task id change after redistribution

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I have a Django model which has a column called `celery_task_id`. I am using `RabbitMQ` as the broker. There's a celery function called `test_celery` which takes a model object as parameter. Now I have the following lines of code which creates a celery task.

```
def create_celery_task():
    celery_task_id = test_celery.apply_async((model_obj,), eta='Future Datetime Object')
    model_obj.celery_task_id = celery_task_id
    model_obj.save()
    ----
    ----
```

Now inside the celery function I am verifying if the task id is same as of the one stored in the DB or not.

```
@app.task
def test_celery(model_obj):
    if model_obj.celery_task_id == test_celery.request.id:
        ## Do something
```

My problem is there are a lot of cases where I can see the task being received and succeeding in the log  but not executing the code inside of if condition.

Is it possible that celery task id changes after redistribution. Or are there any other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

One of the recommendations is not to pass Database/ORM objects into the Celery tasks because the may contain stale data. Try to rewrite the task as:

```
@app.task
def test_celery(model_obj_id):
    model_obj = YourModel.objects.get(id=model_obj_id)
    if model_obj:
        if model_obj.celery_task_id == test_celery.request.id:
            ## Do something
```

Comment: But still it doesn't answer the question. Will `test_celery.request.id` change during rabbitmq sync process, or during re distribution of workers.

Comment: I think that ID is not changing. My guess is that left side of condition is not working, i.e. model_obj.celery_task_id because you provide object to the task. Your guess is that test_celery.request.id is changing during sync process and it causes the problem.